# upgrade gradle to v6.1.1 unable to find method

Tags: android-studio, gradle

> ```
> Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskInputs.property(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs;'.
> Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

It is useful to work through the documentation here, in case any of the detail helps with resolution:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#changes_6.0

My issue turned out to be related to a specific third party plugin, `Greendao3GradlePlugin`.

I have documented my failed steps too so that others can avoid unnecessary steps.

`./gradlew build` fails with error: `Failed to notify project evaluation listener.`

Steps to resolve:

1. Upgrade JDK to version 9: Failed to resolve.
2. Download and install [JDK 9](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase9-archive-downloads.html): Failed to resolve.
3. Install SDK 30.0: Failed to resolve.
4. Add `configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.capabilitiesResolution.all { selectHighestVersion() }
   }` to build.gradle: Failed to resolve.
5. Disabled all third-party plugins: Failed to resolve.
6. Upgrade to `kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72`: Failed to resolve.
7. `./gradlew --scan build` revealed error comes from `Greendao3GradlePlugin`, suggesting this is a project-specific error. Solution is to resolve this specific issue.

Recommendation to others with this problem: use [Gradle Build Scans](https://scans.gradle.com/) to drill down into your build to find the problem third party plugin.